# How to get menus in Unity-2D and XMonad?

Tags: unity-2d, appmenu, xmonad

I am running XMonad with Unity-2D on 11.10 on a dual-head configuration, similar to https://gist.github.com/1300108 and http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Unity_2D

As a commenter notes in the Gist, there are no menus in the panel.

If I run an application with UBUNTU_MENUPROXY unset, the app has regular menus.  If it is set by default (as it is by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80appmenu*` by the presence of the GTK `libappmenu.so` libraries, there are no menus displayed in the panel.

I see that there is an indicator-appmenu package but I don't know how to figure out if it is being loaded or how to add it to the panel.  There is, on the other hand, no appmenu plugin in `/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/`.

Any hints appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Plus the question is very localised Regards,